# Why aren't jQuery items working on Github Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, bootstrap-4, github-pages

I've hosted my project on githu pages, but it doesn't seem to be functioning properly as the elements like collapse, etc are not working. 
There doesn't seem to be any problem in the code as the unhosted html page is functioning smoothly on my device.

Here is the link to my page section with the collapse region, which isn't functional.

> https://cyborg7459.github.io/Mizuxe/#about

This is my code for the page

> https://github.com/cyborg7459/Mizuxe/blob/master/index.html

Please tell me what is the problem here and how to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is cors origin. Change http jquery library to https. You can't reach https to http due to security issues.

http =>http  OK
http =>https OK
https=>http  NOK

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```